# MongoDB Recursive Grouping

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using Mongodb 3.2 -> possibly moving to 3.4
nodejs driver for mongodb (not mongoose)

I have a document collection that looks like this

```
{ _id: "A", title:"title1"}
{ _id: "B", title:"title2"}
{ _id: "G", title:"title3", parents:["A"] }
{ _id: "H", title:"title4", parents:["A", "B"]}
{ _id: "I", title:"title5", parents:["G"]}
```

is it possible to create a single aggregate query to output that looks like this?

```
[
{
  title:"title1"
  children:[
      {title:"title3", children:[ {title:"title5"} ]},
      {title:"title4", children:[] }
  ]
}
{
  title:"title2",
  children:[ 
      {title:"title4", children:[]} 
  ]
}
]
```

The depth of this tree will grow and shrink. it is possible to change the schema to children, parent, parent->ancestor etc.... multiple collections and using $lookup is possible however it would be ideal to use a single collection.

thank you in advance. I have not been able to find answers to this level yet.

Comment: try `$graphLookup` for recursive join

Comment: Graphlookup gets me 90%of the way the with a recursive single array. But not deep nesting. Might be a solution for now...